# Using x11vnc as VNC server, but a really simple Qt-embedded app get hanged after key pressing

Tags: qt, vnc, qtembedded

I am trying to use TightVNC viewer to connect to my VNC server running by x11vnc. Since there is no X server on my embedded device, I start the x11vnc by the following arguments:

> ./x11vnc -rawfb console -pipeinput
>   UINPUT:touch,tslib_cal=/etc/pointercal,direct_abs=/dev/input/event1

I build a very simple Qt-embedded app which only has a push button and a line edit. From the TightVNC viewer I can use mouse to click the push button and it show a message box by my design. However, the app got hanged when I press a key on the keyboard.

The VNC connection is working well because when I restart the app, I can still control it from viewer.

Because the app is just a very simple one, I tend to think this is a bug in Qt? If this is the case, is there any way to avoid or work around this? Or is there any way to control the Qt-embedded app by mouse and keyboard via VNC (also a password protection is necessary)?

The Qt-embedded version is 4.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

Use QtVNC with Qt 4.8.4 and the qws platform - it works well.